# Is there anyway to keep only one week data in redshift table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a source where everyday file get populated and every day it is loaded into redshift table
but I want to keep only one week of data in the table after one week it should delete the data which are older.

Suggest a, way for that.

Answer (score 0):

A common method is:

- Load each day's data into a **separate table**
- Use `CREATE VIEW` to create a combined view of the past week's tables

For example:

```sql
CREATE VIEW data
AS
SELECT * FROM monday_table
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tuesday_table
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM wednesday_table
...etc
```

Your users can simply use the View as a normal table.

- Then, each day when new data has arrived, `DROP` or `TRUNCATE` the oldest table and load the new data
- Either load the new data in the same-named table as the one dropped/truncated, or re-create the View to include this new table and not the dropped one

There is no automatic process to do the above steps, but you could **make it part of the script that runs your Load process**.